# How do I properly overload the << operand to produce the desired results?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, operator-overloading

https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/fun-with-arrays/521/introduction/3294/

I'm following this Leetcode course on Arrays and am trying to follow along using C++ as they use Java, but I'm struggling to get past this part. I just want to read items from the pokedex array I made.

The initial error I got was:

```
No operator << matches these operands.
Array.cpp(16,15) operand types are std::ostream << Pokemon
```

I then tried to overload the << operator as I've seen other people ask on here, but I'm not getting the output I want. When I compile the program as-is, nothing prints.

Can someone explain what I can do to get the desired output?

> Cyndaquill is a fire type at level 5

Also, can someone explain, or point me in the direction of someone who can explain, operator overloading in an easy non-verbose way? A lot of what I've seen on StackOverflow has been overly verbose and confusing. Maybe it's because I'm new to C++, but still.

**Array.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array_Header.hpp"

int main() {
    
    Pokemon pokeDex[15];

    Pokemon Cyndaquill = Pokemon("Cyndaquill", 5, "Fire");
    Pokemon Totodile = Pokemon("Totodile", 5, "Water");
    Pokemon Chikorita = Pokemon("Chikorita", 5, "Grass");

    pokeDex[0] = Cyndaquill;
    pokeDex[1] = Totodile;
    pokeDex[2] = Chikorita;

    std::cout << pokeDex[0];
    std::cout << pokeDex[1];
    std::cout << pokeDex[2];
    std::cout << pokeDex[3];

}
```

**Array_Header.hpp**

```
#include <string>

class Pokemon {

    public:

    //variable declarations
    std::string name;
    int level;
    std::string type;

    //Constructor for the DVD class
    Pokemon(std::string name, int level, std::string type);
    Pokemon() = default;

    //toString function declaration
    std::string toString();

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Pokemon& obj) 
    { 
        return os;
    };

};
```

**Array_Header.cpp**

```
#include "Array_Header.hpp"

//Constructor Definition
Pokemon::Pokemon(std::string name, int level, std::string type){
    this->type = type;
    this->level = level;
    this->name = name;
};


//toString function definition
std::string Pokemon::toString(){
    return this->name + " is a " + this->type + " type at level " + std::to_string(level) + "\n";
};
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code you have posted won't generate the stated error message (but maybe some warnings). We need more info.

Comment: "I'm following this Leetcode course on Arrays and am trying to follow along using C++ as they use Java" This sounds like a weird idea. There's plenty of material aimed at teaching C++.

Comment: In your `operator<<`, you just `return os;` without taking any action on it or using `obj` in any way. That's why you get no output, `std::cout << pokeDex[0];` doesn't do anything to `std::cout`.

Comment: You should add `#include <ostream>` to `Array_Header.hpp`; otherwise there could be problems with the compiler not knowing what `std::ostream` actually is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your operator overload for `<<` to print to an `std::ostream` an object of type `Pokemon` does nothing but return the `os` parameter. You need to add the logic for printing inside of here, which would look something like this:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Pokemon& obj) 
{
    os << obj.toString();
    return os;
};
```

Comment: @273K The OP stated that was the error that they received before creating the operator overload, and then asked why the overload did not do what was expected.

Comment: Sorry, the silly question content, emphasing something that is not a question subject. As for the comments, I'm not a single person who is confused by the question.

Comment: @cryptxum Thanks for the help. I had to remove (const) from the definition in order for it to work. When const was present I received the error "the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function Pokemon::toString". 

I don't really understand that, could you explain?
Thanks!

Comment: This is why you should learn C++ by learning C++, not by learning Java and trying to write something similar. Java doesn't really have a direct equivalent of `const` in C++. The actual thing to do would be to keep the signature of `operator<<` intact, but change `toString` to be a `const` member function so that it can be called from a `const Pokemon` object.

Comment: @NathanPierson Gotcha, thanks for the advice and criticism. I'll try to revise my training.